# Pass arguments in cmd

Tags: cmd, path, arguments, parameter-passing, explorer

**If you type this command at the command line:**

```
explorer %path%
```

> The explorer opens with the specified in% path% folder.

**For example:**

```
explorer C:\Users\%username%\Desktop
```

> The Desktop folder opens in Explorer.

**You can also write the path to the file in% path% and then the file will open.**

**For example:**

```
explorer C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

> Run the browser

- **And the question:**

**Can I pass arguments to startup programs? and how?**

*For example, like this (Not work)*

```
explorer ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" www.youtube.com"
```

*Or so (Not work)*

```
explorer "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "/k notepad"
```

> Thank you in advance

Comment: You generally can't put quotes inside quotes, that makes no sense to your shell.

Comment: You have to look up each programs reference. `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.google.com.au`. Quotes around google are optional. This will work `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k notepad`. Quotes go around a parameter that may have spaces, if you KNOW that it won't have spaces you don't need to use them, but can. Also `%path%` is a system variable so don't use it.

Comment: I edit my question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980027/multi-layer-arguments-in-cmd)

Comment: I edit my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980027/multi-layer-arguments-in-cmd